# onCreate ListView error: not a statement - Android

Tags: android, listview, oncreate

final ListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_list);

According to Android Studio this is not a statement and I am unsure why because it looks fine to me. Perhaps it is in the incorrect placement in the file but I am certain it is not. All it says about it is that It is not a statement which is bugging me. Here is the code it is in with.

CustomizedListView.class:

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Fragment {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, container, false);
    final ListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_list);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }




    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {


        }
    });
}
}
```

game_list is in main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#e5e5e5" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/game_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#e5e5e5"
    android:dividerHeight="6dp"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomizedListView is a fragment of MainActivity.class using actionbarsherlock:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabSwipe mTabSwipe;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabSwipe = new TabSwipe(this, mViewPager);
    mTabSwipe.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Games"), CustomizedListView.class, null);
    mTabSwipe.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Movies"), Purchase_Fragment.class, null);
    mTabSwipe.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Null"), Purchase_Fragment.class, null);


    }
}
```

Logcat after fix:

```
07-20 16:36:41.635    1649-1649/com.launchpadsw.releasedates E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-20 16:36:41.899    1649-1649/com.launchpadsw.releasedates E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    at com.launchpadsw.releasedates.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:45)
    at com.launchpadsw.releasedates.CustomizedListView.onCreate(CustomizedListView.java:49)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1437)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:807)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:801)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1062)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: why do you need the final modifier remove it. you can declare the variables as class members

Comment: If I remove the modifier I then have the problem of it saying Expression expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have this

```
     ListView list;
```

Replace this

```
      final ListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_list);
```

by

```
      list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_list);
```

You can remove the final modifier. Declare `ListView list` as a class member.

To answer the edited question

You are getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` which occurs when you are doing network related operation on the ui thread.

Use `AsyncTask` or `thread`.

check this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

check this for asynctask

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

This

```
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
```

should be done on a background thread.

AsyncTask :

```
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             xml= parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
    return null;
}

}
```

To invoke

```
  new TheTask().execute();
```

Declare `String xml;` as a class member.

Comment: I am now getting an error which I cannot work out in the logcat forcing the app to close unexpectedly. Check the bottom of my post for the logcat now.

Comment: @ThePoloDoc if your doing network related task you should use `asynctask` or `thread`.

Comment: @ThePoloDoc move your network related operation inside a thread. check the links posted in the edited post.

Comment: @ThePoloDoc keep the original post so that it does not mislead people who visit the post. put a edit section to post updates. your original question was answered.

Comment: So it would use something along the lines of: private class AccessURL extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, URL>{                           
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {       String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
} - If this is incorrect please tell me as I am not understanding AsyncTasks well.

Comment: @ThePoloDoc check the edited post. something like that should work. As a side note you cannot update ui from a background thread. you can display a progress dialog in `onPreExecute` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: What do you mean by declare String xml; as class member? Also xml is expecting an expression still and it cannot resolve parser as a symbol. I really am having trouble today.

Comment: as class member meaning within the scope of the class. name it `String myxmlstring` to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have completely messed this up. Do you mind editing your question to have my code and adding in yours at the bottom of your answer? Just do the bits which are actually changed in the file is all that is needed. I am unsure what I have done wrong and I have deleted something accidentally and messed it up.

Comment: @ThePoloDoc post a new question with the updated code. if not i the community will help you. this will lead to long discussion. post a new thread.